# How do I save pandasProfile report using Tkinter asktosavefile module?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

When I run the code and enter a file name and click on save the application generates HTML then it says rendering HTML and after that is done it closes. when I look at the file generated it appears to be empty.

*Here is my code:*

```py
def SaveReport():
    profile = ProfileReport( df, minimal=True, title='Profiling Report', explorative=True)
    html = profile.to_html()
    files = [('HTML Files', '*.html')]
    file = asksaveasfile(mode="wb", title="Save File",
                         filetypes=files, defaultextension=files)

    if file is None:
        return None

    html_to_save = open(html, "rb").read()
    file.write(html_to_save)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating matters. Just `write` to the `file` directly:

```
def SaveReport():
    html = df.to_html()
    files = [('HTML Files', '*.html')]
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w", title="Save File",
                                    filetypes=files, defaultextension=files)
    if file:
        file.write(html)
        file.close()
```

Comment: Okay, it worked but the app crashes after writing to a file